# Why does Rust not perform implicit deref coercion in match patterns?

Tags: rust, dereference, coercion

After reading the section in the Rust book on [Smart Pointers and Interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html#having-multiple-owners-of-mutable-data-by-combining-rct-and-refcellt), I tried, as a personal exercise, to write a function that would traverse a linked list of smart pointers and return the "last" element in the list:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum List {
    Cons(Rc<RefCell<i32>>, Rc<List>),
    Nil,
}

use crate::List::{Cons, Nil};

fn get_last(list: &List) -> &List {
    match list {
        Nil | Cons(_, Nil) => list,
        Cons(_, next_list) => get_last(next_list),
    }
}
```

This code results in the following error:

```
   |         Nil | Cons(_, Nil) => list,
   |                       ^^^ expected struct `std::rc::Rc`, found enum `List
```

I was able to get it to work by using a "match guard" and explicitly dereferncing on the `Cons(_, x)` pattern:

```
fn get_last(list: &List) -> &List {
    match list {
        Nil => list,
        Cons(_, next_list) if **next_list == Nil => list,
        Cons(_, next_list) => get_last(next_list),
    }
}
```

Given what I've learned about implicit dereferencing and the `Deref` trait implementation for `Rc`, I would have expected my first attempt to work.  Why must I explicitly dereference in this example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, we need to understand what deref coercion is. If `T` derefs to `U` and `x` is a value of type `T`, then:

- `*x` is `*Deref::deref(&x)`
- `&T` can be coerced to `&U`
- `x.method()` will check type `U` during method resolution.

How method resolution works is when you call a method on a type, it first checks for a method by adding nothing to the type, then adding `&`, then adding `&mut`, then derefing. So, when figuring out which method to call for `x.method()`, it'll first check for a method that takes `T`, then `&T`, then `&mut T`, then `U`, then `&U`, then `&mut U` ([read more here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html)). This **does not** apply to operators. Therefore, `==` will not coerce the differing types, which is why you must explicitly dereference.

But what if we did use a method, like `.eq` in the `PartialEq` trait? Things get interesting. The following code fails:

```rust
fn get_last(list: &List) -> &List {
    match list {
        Nil => list,
        Cons(_, next_list) if next_list.eq(Nil) => list,
        Cons(_, next_list) => get_last(next_list),
    }
}
```

but the following succeeds:

```rust
fn get_last(list: &List) -> &List {
    match list {
        Nil => list,
        // notice how it's Nil.eq and not next_list.eq
        Cons(_, next_list) if Nil.eq(next_list) => list,
        Cons(_, next_list) => get_last(next_list),
    }
}
```

Why is this? Let's look at the first example:

`next_list` is of type `&Rc<List>`, so it starts searching for a `.eq` method. It immediately finds one defined in the `PartialEq` implementation for `Rc` with signature `fn eq(&self, other: &Rc<List>)`. However, `other` is of type `List` in this case, which cannot be coerced to `&Rc<List>`.

Then why does the second work?
`Nil` is of type `List`, so it starts searching for a `.eq` method. It can't find any for `List`, so it tries `&List` next, where it finds the derived `PartialEq` implmentation with signature `fn eq(&self, other: &List)`. In this case, other is of type `&Rc<List>`, which can be coerced to `&List` because of its `Deref` implementation. This means that everything typechecks properly and the code works.

As to why your first attempt didn't work, it appears to just not be a feature in rust, and there's [a proposal to add it dating back to 2017](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2099).